# Maintaining and updating large subsets of SQL results in an efficient manner

Tags: database, postgresql, scalability

In our web stack, I'm working on implementing a feature that allows users to basically specify several filter conditions (from now referred to as *list*), which are fetched from tables in a Postgres database. A user can have many of those lists with each list having conditions like "contains" or "equal to" for a set of columns.

The logic involved in that is relatively straightforward, but the problem starts because the customer wants to be able to view the changes/updates to the list query results on daily basis (so essentially storing daily snapshot of deltas) and some of those filter conditions may be slow and run large tables on non-indexed columns (the tables in question are 2-3 million rows each).

At the moment we use Redis and Postgres as our storage backends, and I'm not entirely sure what's the best way to represent or even manage those daily updates, as well as indexing them per list per user.

- The biggest problem I see is determining the difference between the results of the what the query returned yesterday (last run) and today (current run), and the previous storing result set for each list would be inefficient, I suspect. And without it, I don't know how we would figure out what's changed between the two queries (the changes can occur from many places in the system so catching all of them and handling them in application code could be a significant amount of work).
- Providing the difference between the result sets is known (requires knowing each field and its new value), a related table would be populated with a list of changes

I'm sure similar problems are solved by a lot of software dealing with analytical data but I'm not really familiar with how to solve this in an efficient manner and I don't want to try to reinvent the wheel, so I wanted to ask if anyone has any ideas/suggestions for how to implement that (perhaps using additional software as well as PG and Redis)?

To elaborate, this operation has to be performed every 12 hours (currently) for all existing lists in bulk, most likely using a daemon (or just a cronjob) that invokes the updater.

*(sorry if the question seems vague, I tried to outline every possible aspect of it I could think of but I'm not sure I've done it well enough)*

Comment: So your back end is probably written in some language - Python, Go, PHP, Perl, Java, so you have a way to make things asynchronous  using Redis and some sort of Message Queue , threading, pooling.

Comment: The lists are (parameters for) selections made by the users? The deltas are deltas in the lists, or in the results of *executing* them?

Comment: Yes it's essentially a set of conditions that are translated into a query. The deltas only need to be calculated between two query results - old results that the batch job got last time and new results the current batch job got. The new results then become *old* results for the next execution of the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we do is store all changes in an audit table using triggers, storing the table's key as a text array, and the changed values (old and new) as two jsonb fields:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION text2intsafe(text) RETURNS int AS $$
  SELECT CASE WHEN $1 ~ '^ *-?\d{1,9} *$' THEN $1::int END
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS crm.audit (
  audit_id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  date timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  username text NOT NULL DEFAULT crm.f_user(),
  tableclass regclass NOT NULL,
  action text NOT NULL CHECK (action IN ('I','U','D')),
  id text[] NOT NULL,
  old_data jsonb NULL,
  new_data jsonb NULL
);

CREATE INDEX ON audit (date);
CREATE INDEX ON audit (tableclass, id);
CREATE INDEX ON audit USING gin (old_data);
CREATE INDEX audit_tableclass_id_idx ON audit (tableclass, text2intsafe(id[1]));

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_audit_get_value(p_tableclass regclass, p_date timestamptz, p_id text[], p_object text[]) RETURNS jsonb AS $$
SELECT COALESCE(
  (SELECT a.old_data#>$4
   FROM audit a
   WHERE a.tableclass = $1 AND a.date >= $2 AND id = $3 AND (a.old_data#>$4) IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY a.date LIMIT 1),
  (SELECT a.new_data#>$4
   FROM audit a
   WHERE a.tableclass = $1 AND a.date < $2 AND id = $3 AND (a.new_data#>$4) IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY a.date DESC LIMIT 1))
$$ LANGUAGE SQL SECURITY DEFINER STABLE STRICT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_audit_get_text(p_tableclass regclass, p_date timestamptz, p_id text[], p_object text[]) RETURNS text AS $$
SELECT COALESCE(
  (SELECT a.old_data#>>$4
   FROM audit a
   WHERE a.tableclass = $1 AND a.date >= $2 AND id = $3 AND (a.old_data#>$4) IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY a.date LIMIT 1),
  (SELECT a.new_data#>>$4
   FROM audit a
   WHERE a.tableclass = $1 AND a.date < $2 AND id = $3 AND (a.new_data#>$4) IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY a.date DESC LIMIT 1))
$$ LANGUAGE SQL SECURITY DEFINER STABLE STRICT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_jsonb_diff(jsonb, jsonb) RETURNS jsonb AS $$
-- return an object with attributes from $2 that differ from those of $1
SELECT json_object_agg(v2.key, CASE COALESCE(t2, t1)
                                WHEN 'object' THEN public.f_json_diff(CASE WHEN t1 IS NULL THEN '{}'::jsonb ELSE v1.value END, CASE WHEN t2 IS NULL THEN '{}'::jsonb ELSE v2.value END)
                                WHEN 'array'  THEN public.f_json_array_diff(CASE WHEN t1 = 'array' THEN v1.value ELSE '[]'::jsonb END, CASE WHEN t2 = 'array' THEN v2.value ELSE '[]'::jsonb END)
                                ELSE v2.value END)::jsonb
FROM      jsonb_each(COALESCE(CASE WHEN jsonb_typeof($2) = 'object' THEN $2 END, '{}'::jsonb)) v2
LEFT JOIN jsonb_each(COALESCE(CASE WHEN jsonb_typeof($1) = 'object' THEN $1 END, '{}'::jsonb)) v1 on (v1.key = v2.key)
LEFT JOIN LATERAL NULLIF(jsonb_typeof(v1.value), 'null') t1 ON (true)
LEFT JOIN LATERAL NULLIF(jsonb_typeof(v2.value), 'null') t2 ON (true)
WHERE v1.value IS DISTINCT FROM v2.value
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tf_audit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
  _id text[];
  _key int2vector;
  _orow jsonb;
  _nrow jsonb;
  _odata jsonb;
  _ndata jsonb;
BEGIN
  _key := indkey FROM pg_index WHERE indrelid = TG_RELID AND indisunique ORDER BY indisprimary DESC LIMIT 1;

  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
    _ndata := to_jsonb(NEW);
    _id := ARRAY(SELECT _ndata->>attname FROM pg_attribute WHERE attrelid = TG_RELID AND attnum = ANY(_key) ORDER BY attnum);
  ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
    _nrow := to_jsonb(NEW);
    _orow := to_jsonb(OLD);

    _odata := f_jsonb_diff(_nrow, _orow);
    _ndata := f_jsonb_diff(_orow, _nrow);

    _id := ARRAY(SELECT _nrow->>attname FROM pg_attribute WHERE attrelid = TG_RELID AND attnum = ANY(_key) ORDER BY attnum);
  ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
    _odata := to_jsonb(OLD);
    _id := ARRAY(SELECT _odata->>attname FROM pg_attribute WHERE attrelid = TG_RELID AND attnum = ANY(_key) ORDER BY attnum);
  END IF;

  IF _odata <> '{}'::jsonb OR _ndata <> '{}'::jsonb THEN
    INSERT INTO audit (username, tableclass, action, id, old_data, new_data)
    VALUES (crm.f_user(), TG_RELID, substring(TG_OP FROM 1 FOR 1), _id, _odata, _ndata);
  END IF;

  RETURN CASE WHEN TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN OLD ELSE NEW END;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

And then for each table you want to audit, simply add:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_table_audit BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON table
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE crm.tf_audit();
```

Then with this you can produce accurate deltas between any two points in time for any audited table (from the date you implemented the auditing).